# Rank students in a class based on probabilities in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ranking

I have fit a bayesian model and sampled from the posterior to get probabilities of a student finishing 1st, 2nd, etc. in their class. I would like to rank them by predicted class rank, but must adhere to the constraint that there is a student in every position. I am having a hard time figuring out how to deal with the scenario where two or more students' highest probabilities are for the same position.

Here is an example where rows are students and columns are probs for the nth class rank.

```
0.5  0.25  0.25
0.4  0.32  0.28
0.15 0.35  0.5
```

Here, ranking by rows would have students 1 and 2 both in 1st, and ranking by columns would have student 3 in 2nd and 3rd. It would be ideal for student 2 to get ranked in 2nd since their highest probability is for 1st, but somebody else had a higher probability for it.

Here is the format my data is currently in.

```
observ  rank    student_id  prob    class
<int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <chr>
5766320 1   7203    0.25    FA2022_ENG_1
5766320 2   7203    0.15    FA2022_ENG_1
5766320 3   7203    0.15    FA2022_ENG_1
5766320 4   7203    0.16    FA2022_ENG_1
5766320 5   7203    0.15    FA2022_ENG_1
5766320 6   7203    0.14    FA2022_ENG_1
```

Are there any functions that can accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe do a weighted mean--mean rank weighted by probability--and then sort by that?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks, that slightly raises the overall accuracy, but reduces the accuracy for which student gets 1st. I might play around with it more.